# Spotify pauses when audioplayer starts in my app

Tags: spotify, audio-player

I know this is possible but I haven't found how yet, so I'm asking it.

When starting to play a mp3 sound in my app while 3rd party music is playing, for example Spotify. Spotify pauses, and you have to resume Spotify, to let it play again.

How can I allow Spotify to keep playing while my audioplayer sound starts??

Answer (score 19):

If by "audioplayer" you mean VLC. I noticed recently this behavior on my Mac. According to [VLC's changelog](http://www.videohelp.com/software/vlc-media-player/version-history) under "Changes between 2.1.6 and 2.2.0:" and "Mac OS X Interface:", it states "in addition to iTunes, Spotify is automatically paused on playback start".

To disable this feature, open VLC:

1. Under the VLC menu (top, left of your screen), choose "Preferences"
2. Press "Show All" button (bottom, left)
3. On left side, navigate to: Interface -> Main interfaces -> macosx
4. Under "Control external music players", instead of "Pause iTunes / Spotify", choose "Do nothing"
5. Press "Save" (bottom, right)

Comment: I meant 'my app' as in, the iOS app that I am developing.